# Composing Ant Proprty name from file path element

Tags: dynamic, ant, properties, path

I have the following requirement. In my project there is a directory that hosts set of google protobuf schema files (.proto). Since .proto files should be in sync with other projects my application would communicate with, I would like to have an ANT build task that would validate that local and "remote" .proto files are identical.

Here is a sample project directory structure:

```
${project.root}
  etc
     refData
       refdata.proto
     marketData
       md.proto
```

ANT task would map file path to a property name. Property would in turn be used to lookup remote path. For the sample directory above I should be able to map each .proto file under etc directory to the following properties:

```
refdata.refdata.proto=[configure remote path here]
marketdata.md.proto=[configure remote path here]
```

I am not all that familiar with ANT, what tasks should I use to achieve the above ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project default="all" basedir="."> 
    <target name="all">
        <property name="project.root" value="c:\" />
        <property name="refdata.refdata.proto" value="${project.root}etc\refData\refdata.proto" />
        <echo message="refdata.refdata.proto = ${refdata.refdata.proto}" />
        <property name="marketdata.md.proto" value="${project.root}etc\marketData\md.proto" />
        <echo message="marketdata.md.proto = ${refdata.refdata.proto}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear on one detail, I would like it to be generic so that when new .proto files are added to project all I would need to do is add corresponding property to build.properties, but not need to change build.xml itself. I want ant task to dynamically pick up all proto files, compose property name for each based on proto file path/name and then lookup the property, which would be defined in properties file and contain path to external .proto file.

Answer (score 0):

Files structure:

```
.
├── build.xml
├── etc
│   ├── a
│   │   └── aa.proto
│   └── b
│       └── bb.proto
└── some.properties
```

some.properties:

```
a.aa.proto=propa
b.bb.proto=propb
```

build.xml:

```
<project name="a" default="props" basedir=".">

    <!-- define file containing *.proto propterties -->
    <property name="prop.file" value="some.properties" />

    <target name="props">

        <echo>props file: ${prop.file}</echo>

        <!-- create an OR regex based on file names
            while stripping the path prefix -->
        <pathconvert property="proto.files" pathsep="|">
            <map from="${basedir}/etc/" to="" />
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="**/*.proto" />
            </fileset>
        </pathconvert>
        <echo>proto files: ${proto.files}</echo>

        <!-- load converted regex into new property -->
        <loadresource property="proto.props">
            <!-- use property as a resource, avoids temp files -->
            <propertyresource name="proto.files" />
            <!-- replace / with . -->
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <filetokenizer />
                    <replacestring from="/" to="." />
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>
        <echo>proto props: ${proto.props}</echo>

        <!-- load properties matching the regex -->
        <loadproperties srcfile="${prop.file}">
            <filterchain>
                <containsregex pattern="${proto.props}" />
            </filterchain>
        </loadproperties>

        <!-- confirm -->
        <echo>a:${a.aa.proto}</echo>
        <echo>b:${b.bb.proto}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

build output:

```
Buildfile: /tmp/a/build.xml

props:
     [echo] props file: some.properties
     [echo] proto files: a/aa.proto|b/bb.proto
     [echo] proto props: a.aa.proto|b.bb.proto
     [echo] a:propa
     [echo] b:propb

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```